# SQL Select for multiple where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create SQL Select that returns counts of a certain field based on a field.
So, here is what I am trying to do.

```
Select count(distinct id) as TotalCount, -- this will be the total of id
count(distinct id where type='A') as TotalA, -- this will be total when type='A'
count(distinct id where type='B') as TotalB -- This will be total when type = 'B'
from MyTable
```

Basically, TotalCount = TotalA + TotalB.

How can I achieve this in SQL Select Statement?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select count(distinct id) as TotalCount, -- this will be the total of id
count(distinct case type when 'A' then id else NULL end) as TotalA,
count(distinct case type when 'B' then id else NULL end) as TotalB 
from MyTable;
```

Of course  TotalCount may or may not be TotalA + TotalB, depending on the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
SELECT
  count(distinct id) as TotalCount,
  sum(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0) as TotalA,
  sum(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0) as TotalB,
FROM
  MyTable
```

Count per type:

```
SELECT
  type,
  count(DISTINCT id)
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY
  type
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply UNION the separate queries.

```
  Select 'all' as which, count(distinct id) as Total from mytable
  union 
  select 'a' as which, count(distinct id) where type='A' as Total from mytable
  union
  select 'b' as which, count(distinct id) where type='B' as Total from mytable
```